Error TS2339: Property 'customProperty' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'
I encountered Error TS2339: Property 'customFunction' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.  when trying to build my Angular library.
I am trying to add .d.ts file in my freshly generated library and still encountered the issue during build. I tried the solution from multiple questions here, and yet I still encountered the issue.
Here my steps to replicate:
First I generated new workspace:
ng new test-workspace --create-application=false
Then, inside the workspace, I generate a new Angular Library
cd test-workspace
ng generate library lib-test
After that, I generated a directory in lib-test under lib-test/src/types.
Then, I created a file window.d.ts with following content
declare global { 
    interface Window {
        customFunction: {
            startService: (arg: string) => void;
            endService: (arg: string) => void;
        }
    }
}

export {};

After that, I called window with the custom property in the lib-test.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LibTestService {

  constructor() { 
    window.customFunction.startService("test");
  }
}

On VSCode, there aren't any error Property 'customFunction' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.. But during ng build lib-test, I encountered this error.
Can someone help to point out am I missing any steps for implementing this customFunction?

Alternative:
Try adding types to the tsconfig.
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/lib",
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "types": ["./src/types/index.d.ts"]
  },
  "exclude": ["**/*.spec.ts"]
}

Stackblitz Demo -> npm i -> cd test-workspace -> npm i -> cd projects/lib-test -> npm i -> ng build lib-test

Original Fix:
The fix for the issue is to add the reference to the type using the triple slash include syntax.
/*
* Public API Surface of lib-test
*/
/// <reference path="./types/index.d.ts" />
export * from './lib/lib-test.service';
export * from './lib/lib-test.component';

After doing this the build was successful, The below github issue helped me find the solution (Comment from dherges.
How to add custom typings to a library build? #193
Stackblitz Demo -> npm i -> cd test-workspace -> npm i -> cd projects/lib-test -> npm i -> ng build lib-test

I have tried adding the typeRoots, but I still encountered same error - error TS2339: Property 'customFunction' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.

I tried the Stackblitz Demo, I also encountered same error..

@Kelvin updated my answer

I tried adding the triple slash reference path in the public-api.ts and it works. However, esLint is complaining Do not use a triple slash reference for .d.ts, use 'import' style instead.. I am able to disable the rule for public-api.ts file only. Is there a way to convert it to "import" style?

@Kelvin updated my answer

To fix the compile error, include declaration files in your tsconfig.lib.json:
{
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}


I added the include declaration into tsconfig.lib.json but still encountered the same issue. For reference I am using angular 18.2.12.
